# Universal links on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am starting to get friendly with deep linking and have read about universal links in iOS 9.3 above. I want to open my app from an email through deep linking.

I am able to do it with deep linking using universal links but how do I do it for below versions. Please help.

Comment: try this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive

Comment: is there any other way? @KKRocks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom URI scheme. Obviously you also need to do OS version detection to make sure you are using the appropriate approach.

The recommendation to try Firebase Dynamic Links or [Branch](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) is a good one; it will save you a lot of work and headache.